# How to using Selenium IDE with Fabric Js

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to test Selenium in my web-app using Fabric js but I don't have any solution for select object on fabric canvas by Selenium IDE.

Comment: You should be able to use javascript to obtain some information about them.

For example:
https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Advanced_animations$samples/First_demo?revision=730863
ball.color="red";
ball.draw();


But without knowing what you are trying to do with the canvas object, I'm not sure how else to advise you.

Comment: My canvas use Fabric Js library and it can draw a rect by click on canvas and move mouse to draw. I can work out with some command in Selenium IDE like mouseDownAt and mouseMoveAt. But it not alway exactly point in canvas as I expected. Maybe it about resolution of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me when run against http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/

```
<tr>
    <td>mouseDownAt</td>
    <td>css=canvas.upper-canvas.</td>
    <td>200,10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseMoveAt</td>
    <td>css=canvas.upper-canvas.</td>
    <td>300,100</td>
</tr>
```

I believe the coordinates are the coordinates within the element. So if you select the right locator, it should be relative to the canvas... if you're selecting the wrong locator (like the whole window frame), all bets are off

Comment: That solution I was try and it really work. I just have some small problem is  my canvas is dynamic resolution. If my test case is just in small screen solution, it will wrong in bigger screen solution. It just a small problem, maybe I can just pass it with static screen solution test. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you just get the size of the canvas object? or set the window size?

Comment: What do you mean "set the window size ?" How can I do that in Selenium IDE ? By the way, in my web app, when I set window size maximize, test case go right as I expected, but when I re-size window size smaller, it draw wrong coordinate as I expect. I still don't know where coordinates in command are.